# Auto cut on thermal printer (php)

Tags: php, thermal-printer

How can i perform auto cut on Epson TMT82 from PHP File? bellow is my config file.

Config:

```
$tmpdir = sys_get_temp_dir();
$file = tempnam($tmpdir, 'ctk');
$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
$condensed = Chr(27) . Chr(33) . Chr(4);
$bold1 = Chr(27) . Chr(69);
$bold0 = Chr(27) . Chr(70);
$initialized = chr(27) . chr(64);
$condensed1 = chr(15);
$condensed0 = chr(18);
$Data = $initialized;
$Data .= $condensed1;
```

Printing:

```
fwrite($handle, $Data);
fclose($handle);
copy($file, "//localhost/printer");  # printing
unlink($file)
```

Comment: Well, the control code for a cut is ESC i, so I'd throw a `chr(27) . chr(105)` out after your data and see what happens...

Comment: sory before, i'm totaly new in this. do i declare one variable after $Data .= $condesed1; or?

Comment: Am I missing something, or have you skipped the bit of your code where you actually send the writing you want to print to the printer?

Comment: i just want to print "Print Test" on the papper

Comment: Well, try printing `chr(27) . chr(105)` after you've printed "Print Test" and see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write chr(29) + 'V' (or chr(86)), and then the values for m and n, depending on the exact function you want to use as per the manual below (if you just want to cut without feeding at all, you want to use function A, which means you can just follow with a 0 (or 48, not sure why they mentioned both numbers in the manual...!?), like so:

`chr(29) . "V" . 0`

https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87

(you need to be logged on to read this reference, but registering is free)

Edited: the chr() code for 'V' is 86, not 56

Edit2: Just to comment on what Matt Gibson said; chr(27) . chr(105) should also work on your model (just checked, also chr(27) . chr(109)), but it's an obsolete command, you should be using chr(29) . "V". In any case, some printers like to receive these sorts of commands on their own instead of having them along with the rest of the string.

Once you get this right, you should probably define a variable with the type of cut that you want. Ex. $cutPaper = chr(29) . "V" . 0;

Comment: $Data .= chr(29) . 'V' . 0;

Comment: Sorry I don't have one to test out here... try to print just the cut command on it's own... (as in, assign chr(29) . 'V' . 0 to a single variable and send only this to the printer. Also... if you notice on the manual page that I posted, there are several options for this command, you can try to follow the 'V' with 48, or 1, or 49, etc... problem is that on this manual there are no non-native examples so it will probably take you a couple of tries to get it just right in php

Comment: OK, looking at an old sample here, just found what may be the problem, I think the Epson models take the parameter for GS V as char, not reading the number; so try this: `$cutPaper = chr(29) . "V" . chr(48) . chr(0);`